# Let T be a linear transformation on the real vector space $\mathbb{R^n}$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $T ^2 =μT$ for same $μ∈\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on the real vector space $\mathbb R^n$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $T^2 =\mu T$ for some $\mu\in\mathbb R$ . Then which of the following is/are true?

> 1. $\|Tx\| = |\mu| \|x\|$ for all $x \in\mathbb {R^n}$
> 2. If $\|Tx\| =  \| x\| $for some non zero vector $x \in\mathbb R^n$, then $\mu=\pm1$
> 3. $T= \mu I$ where $I$ is the identity transformation on $\mathbb R^n$
> 4. If $\|Tx \|>\|x\|$ for a non zero vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $T$ is necessarily singular.

I am completely stuck on it. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Consider $T=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2}&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ for items 1-3. In each of item 1 and item 2, find a suitable $x$ to refute the statement. For item 4, consider $T=2I$.

Comment: can u elaborate please.thanks

Comment: i am slightly confuse how to calculate the norm here

Comment: Does your textbook specify the norm? If not, we usually take the Euclidean 2-norm, i.e. $\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$. In our case, $\|(x,y)^T\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, i.e. calculate the length of a vector using Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: Why can't (2) true?$ ||T(x)||=||x|| \implies ||\lambda x||=||x|| \implies (1-|\lambda))||x||=0 \implies $$\lambda=\pm1$

Comment: @Unknownx The $T$ in my answer already gives a counterexample to (2): when $x=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)^T$, we have $\|Tx\|=\|x\|=1$. However, $T^2=\sqrt{2}T$ and $\sqrt{2}\ne\pm1$.

Comment: @user1551 I think $||Tx|| = 2$ for your $x$ in the previous comment.

Comment: @GA316 $Tx=\pmatrix{\sqrt{2}&0\\ 0&0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\ 1}\right)=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$ is a unit vector.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Thanks for the clarification :)