# Linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $T^{2}=\lambda T.$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $T^{2}=\lambda T$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then which of the following is/are true?

$1.\|T(x)\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$

$2.$ If $\|T(x)\|=\|x\|$ for some non-zero $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $\lambda=\pm 1.$

$3.T=\lambda I$ where $I$ is the identity transformation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

$4.$ If $\|T(x)\|>\|x\|$ for a nonzero vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},$ then $T$ is singular.

According to me since $T^{2}=\lambda T$ we have $T$ satisfies the polynomial $x^{2}-\lambda x.$ So choices for its minimal polynomial are $x,x-\lambda,x(x-\lambda).$ So $3$rd option is clearly incorrect and $4$th option is not satisfied if $T=I$ and hence correct one. I am confused in first two options . Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let T be a linear transformation on the real vector space $R^n$ over $R$ such that $T ^2 =μT$ for same $μ∈R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257634/let-t-be-a-linear-transformation-on-the-real-vector-space-rn-over-r-such-th)